# Plumbing: 3/4 GHT male and 3/4 BSP Female

Tags: plumbing

Can a 3/4 inch GHT male thread fit in a 3/4 BSP female connector ?

Comment: With two very big wrenches, I'm sure you could make them fit, but it might not be water tight. Give us an idea of what you're trying to do and I'm sure you'll get good suggestions on how to go about it. Give us your proposed solution and we can't really help you much. See: [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1):

If GHT means "Garden Hose Thread", then the web says, no, they're not compatible. However, GHT to BSP adapters do exist, according to the web.